# Controller to generate file for download works in development but fails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have this controller that works in my development environment. It's triggered by a user clicking a link and having a `.rdp` be generated for downloading. Works in my development environment, however, when trying to use it on *Heroku*, I'm being redirected to the root page.

I just performed a `git push` to *heroku* and it's telling me that everything is up to date.

**my controller**

```
def createrdpfile
jumpsquare = Jumpsquare.find(params[:id])
file = Tempfile.new(jumpsquare.ipordns.to_s + '.rdp')
file.write("screen mode id:i:2
  desktopwidth:i:1436
  desktopheight:i:925
  session bpp:i:16
  auto connect:i:1
  full address:s:" + jumpsquare.ipordns.to_s + "
  compression:i:1
  keyboardhook:i:2
  audiomode:i:2
  redirectdrives:i:0
  redirectprinters:i:0
  redirectcomports:i:0
  redirectsmartcards:i:0
  displayconnectionbar:i:1
  alternate shell:s:
  shell working directory:s:
  disable wallpaper:i:1
  disable full window drag:i:1
  disable menu anims:i:1
  disable themes:i:1
  bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
  winposstr:s:0,3,0,0,800,600
  redirectclipboard:i:1
  redirectposdevices:i:0
  drivestoredirect:s:
  autoreconnection enabled:i:1
  authentication level:i:0
  prompt for credentials:i:0
  negotiate security layer:i:1
  remoteapplicationmode:i:0
  allow desktop composition:i:0
  allow font smoothing:i:0
  disable cursor setting:i:0
  gatewayhostname:s:
  gatewayusagemethod:i:0
  gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
  gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0"
)
file.close
send_file(file.path, :filename => jumpsquare.ipordns.to_s + '.rdp', :type=>'application/rdp')
#send_file file.path, :type=>'application/rdp'
end
```

**heroku tail log**

```
2013-12-08T03:54:50.830006+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/jumpsquares/286/createrdpfile" for 99.53.77.161 at 2013-12-08 03:54:50 +0000
2013-12-08T03:54:50.830729+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/jumpsquares/286/createrdpfile" for 99.53.77.161 at 2013-12-08 03:54:50 +0000
2013-12-08T03:54:50.835417+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by JumpsquaresController#createrdpfile as HTML
2013-12-08T03:54:50.835417+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by JumpsquaresController#createrdpfile as HTML
2013-12-08T03:54:50.835657+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"286"}
2013-12-08T03:54:50.835657+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"286"}
2013-12-08T03:54:50.878697+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://www.jumpsquares.net/jumpsquares
2013-12-08T03:54:50.878697+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://www.jumpsquares.net/jumpsquares
2013-12-08T03:54:50.879290+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 7.6ms)
2013-12-08T03:54:50.879290+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 7.6ms)
2013-12-08T03:54:50.888283+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/jumpsquares/286/createrdpfile host=www.jumpsquares.net fwd="99.53.77.161" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=60ms status=302 bytes=104
2013-12-08T03:54:51.072305+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/jumpsquares" for 99.53.77.161 at 2013-12-08 03:54:51 +0000
2013-12-08T03:54:51.073470+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/jumpsquares" for 99.53.77.161 at 2013-12-08 03:54:51 +0000
2013-12-08T03:54:51.075021+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by JumpsquaresController#index as HTML
2013-12-08T03:54:51.076274+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by JumpsquaresController#index as HTML
2013-12-08T03:54:51.304897+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered jumpsquares/index.html.erb within layouts/application (186.4ms)
2013-12-08T03:54:51.305084+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered jumpsquares/index.html.erb within layouts/application (186.4ms)
2013-12-08T03:54:51.319162+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (12.8ms)
2013-12-08T03:54:51.319270+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (12.8ms)
2013-12-08T03:54:51.321032+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2013-12-08T03:54:51.321106+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2013-12-08T03:54:51.321501+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 245ms (Views: 144.5ms | ActiveRecord: 71.3ms)
2013-12-08T03:54:51.321899+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 245ms (Views: 144.5ms | ActiveRecord: 71.3ms)
2013-12-08T03:54:51.331901+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/jumpsquares host=www.jumpsquares.net fwd="99.53.77.161" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=378ms status=200 bytes=27976
```

Comment: Have you confirmed you are running the same versions of Ruby?

Comment: DO u have any type of restrictions on production environment that is different from development?

Comment: from my reading so far... it looks like I need to specify something along the lines of "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/# so i can write to the Heroku /tmp/ directory. but I need to figure out the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write this to a file to send it, just send it right away with `send_data`:

```
def createrdpfile
  jumpsquare = Jumpsquare.find(params[:id])
  data = "screen mode id:i:2
    desktopwidth:i:1436
    desktopheight:i:925
    session bpp:i:16
    auto connect:i:1
    full address:s:" + jumpsquare.ipordns.to_s + "
    compression:i:1
    keyboardhook:i:2
    audiomode:i:2
    redirectdrives:i:0
    redirectprinters:i:0
    redirectcomports:i:0
    redirectsmartcards:i:0
    displayconnectionbar:i:1
    alternate shell:s:
    shell working directory:s:
    disable wallpaper:i:1
    disable full window drag:i:1
    disable menu anims:i:1
    disable themes:i:1
    bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
    winposstr:s:0,3,0,0,800,600
    redirectclipboard:i:1
    redirectposdevices:i:0
    drivestoredirect:s:
    autoreconnection enabled:i:1
    authentication level:i:0
    prompt for credentials:i:0
    negotiate security layer:i:1
    remoteapplicationmode:i:0
    allow desktop composition:i:0
    allow font smoothing:i:0
    disable cursor setting:i:0
    gatewayhostname:s:
    gatewayusagemethod:i:0
    gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
    gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0"

  send_data(data, :filename => jumpsquare.ipordns.to_s + '.rdp', :type=>'application/rdp')
end
```

Comment: this solution still isn't working. still doing the redirection on heroku. It does work on the development environment though.

Comment: Show the full source of your controller then, you probably have a filter that's preventing this from running.

Comment: here is the entire controller - https://github.com/kacole2/JumpSquares/blob/herokuprod/app/controllers/jumpsquares_controller.rb

Comment: One of these two filters `before_filter :authenticate_user!`, `load_and_authorize_resource` is causing this redirect to happen. You're probably not logged in to the Heroku version.

Comment: i'm 99.9% sure i'm not doing this wrong. i just loaded your version on heroku. i've logged out, logged back in, refreshed and even tried in another browser... it's still redirecting.

Comment: to try it out for yourself. register with jumpsquares.net, create a new jumpsquare and select "RDP" as the server access method as you're filling it out. After it's created, if you click on the server link, it's supposed to generate the .rdp file but instead it is re-directing.

Comment: Remove the `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied ...` block from your `ApplicationController` and look at what happens.

Comment: that's an innate piece that CanCan automatically generates. It's there to help with any case that a user doesn't have access to a certain page. A user has access to create the .rdp file, i have demonstrated this in the development environment. Removing this piece of code has made every controller error out.

Comment: If removing it makes every controller error out maybe the **permissions are not set** anywhere in the database or for this specific user and that's why it **redirects** you even if you **are** logged in.

Comment: i don't think that is correct because it works perfectly in development. i still believe it is a problem not being able to write to heroku on the tmp space.

Comment: If you're using `send_data` there's no `temp filesystem` issue. And **you are seeing the error now**, how can you believe it is something else when you are clearly seeing your user does not have permissions set?

Comment: I have permissions set everywhere in the application. for instance, if you register, you will not be able to see the administration back end. Everything in the entire application, permissions included, all works perfectly...the only thing not being generated is this rdp generator. and it works in the development environment using Postgresql, same thing as heroku.  I'm not seeing the error messages in the heroku logs... all it shows is Redirected to http://www.jumpsquares.net/jumpsquares

Comment: ok.... you were totally right... it turned out to be a CanCan permission issue... my development environment was using the admin account and not the regular user account.  I added "can :createrdpfile, [Jumpsquare]" to CanCan and it's working... i'm going to award points because your idea is cleaner than creating a file